# Retrieving Only Selected Field Using LINQ

Tags: linq

i have a problems regarding on filtering my code in retrieving companyName from its table..when i query here is the result .. please see my code

```
 Sub call_customers(ByVal dgv_customers As DataGridView)
        Dim customers_name = From cust In dbcon.Customers _
       Select cust.CustomerID, cust.CompanyName Order By CompanyName Ascending
        dgv_customers.DataSource = customers_name
    End Sub
```

the display is CustomerID and CompanyName.. yeah its true.. no problem with the code..

and if i only select cust.companyname the result is this ....like this code

```
Sub call_customers(ByVal dgv_customers As DataGridView)
        Dim customers_name = From cust In dbcon.Customers _
            Select cust.CompanyName
        dgv_customers.DataSource = customers_name
    End Sub
```

the output is this...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVN2I.png)

no display and it says length.. why? newbie in LINQ sir ..

please help..

Comment: the problem is in your GridView and not in the linq query itself for sure, can you share your grid configuration?

Comment: is there any config to gridview sir? is it need to configure the grid?

Comment: if you share the key parts of your code I can help you, maybe upload to github and I can download and examine, the code you pasted seems fine

Comment: Sub sample(ByVal views As DataGridView)
        Dim sample = (From cs In dbcon.Customers
          Select New With {Key cs.CompanyName} Distinct.ToList)
        views.DataSource = sample
    End Sub

Comment: thanks for your help sir. i got it . thank you sir.. i have another problem..is it possible that the result of my query displayed in my datagridview  will display to combo box?

Comment: yes, it is, do you need code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Originally, you were giving the grid an object, and it was displaying each of the properties of that object.

Now that you are giving it a string, it is doing the same thing, but now, the only property on the string is the length,